# When a person clicks on a link and it opens on a new tab, is it possible to redirect the older page to some other particular page?

Tags: html, redirect

...When a person clicks on a link and it opens on a new tab, is it possible to redirect the older page(from which new tab was opened) to some other page?

Comment: how? is it possible?

Comment: .htaccess in Apache. Or a simple meta tag in the leading page: like <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://domain.com/redirectionpage.html'" />

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab and change the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268464/how-to-open-a-new-tab-and-change-the-current-page)

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268464/how-to-open-a-new-tab-and-change-the-current-page)

Comment: @fusion3k..thanks for the advice..but my website is built in HTML...and all the answers are in javascript.

Comment: HTML is not as much powerful to do the one you wanted. You should try `JS/Jquery` .

Comment: okay thank you..it worked.!

Comment: FYI : `onclick="location` is `JS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a href="otherpage.php" target="_blank" onclick="location='thispagechange.php'">
    go to other page
</a>
```

Clicking this link will do two things:

- Because of the `href` and `target` attributes, a new page opens that loads *otherpage.php*;
- Because of the `onclick` attribute the current page also navigates to another page, in this case *thispagechange.php*.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery worked for me. Have a look.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="redrect" target="_blank">Redirect</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".redrect").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            refLink = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            location.href = refLink;
            window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + "stackoverflow.com" + '?param=1', "_blank", '', false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why involving jQuery in this trivial task?